# Multi dimensional array assignment in verilog, without loop?

Tags: multidimensional-array, verilog

How can one assign a multi dimensional array if it is a wire, in a single line?

```
assign TO[W1:0][W2:0] = cntrl ? FROM1[W1:0][W2:0] : FROM2[W1:0][W2:0];
```

I get a syntax error if I use this.

Is there any other way other than using `generate` or `for` loops?

Comment: Can you show your types and your specific error message?

Comment: In verilog, this is impossible without a loop or without slices. A specific error message for ncvlog is "Memory or an array reference requires an index."  In iverilog the message is "Cannot assign to array xxxx. Did you forget a word index?"

Comment: In other words, an N-dimensional array will require N-1 `for` loops in Verilog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using SystemVerilog to make aggregate assignments to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To assign an unpacked arrays braces with tick `'{ and }` are used, provided all the values of the array should be assigned.

usage example

```
module top ( input i);

  wire d [0:1][0:3];
  wire a [0:1][0:3]='{ '{1,1,1,1}, '{1,1,1,1} };
  wire b [0:1][0:3]='{ '{0,0,0,0}, '{0,0,0,0} };

  assign  d = i? (' { '{a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3]},'{b[1][0],b[1][1],b[1][2],b[1][3]}}):
                 (' { '{b[1][0],b[1][1],b[1][2],b[1][3]},'{a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3]}});
endmodule
```

Here `wire a [0:1][0:3]='{ '{1,1,1,1}, '{1,1,1,1} };` and `wire b [0:1][0:3]='{ '{0,0,0,0}, '{0,0,0,0} };`  represents

```
// a[0][0] = 1  b[0][0] = 0
// a[0][1] = 1  b[0][1] = 0
// a[0][2] = 1  b[0][2] = 0
// a[0][3] = 1  b[0][3] = 0
// a[1][0] = 1  b[1][0] = 0
// a[1][1] = 1  b[1][1] = 0
// a[1][2] = 1  b[1][2] = 0
// a[1][3] = 1  b[1][3] = 0
```

Working example can be found in the [eda-playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/UQt) link

Comment: Although legally correct, this syntax is not relevant to the questions

Comment: @dave_59 Yes, although it is SV, since it was mentioned without using generate or for loops I took the alternate approach

Comment: The problem here is is `W1` and `W2` MSBs in the OP are module parameters derived from instantiation.   In other words, this syntax doesn't work for arbitrarily large arrays.  But this answer is interesting if the array sizes are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Two pure verilog solutions: (Assuming `W1` and `W2` are parameters, not variables)

```
// 'TO' must be a reg
integer i,j;
always @* begin
  for(i=0; i<=W1; i=i+1) begin
    for(j=0; j<=W2; j=j+1) begin
      TO[i][j] = cntrl ? FROM1[i][j] : FROM2[i][j];
    end
  end
end
```

```
// 'TO' must be a wire
genvar i,j;
generate
  for(i=0; i<=W1; i=i+1) begin
    for(j=0; j<=W2; j=j+1) begin
      assign TO[i][j] = cntrl ? FROM1[i][j] : FROM2[i][j];
    end
  end
endgenerate
```